# Trouble printing Arabic ligature ﷺ SALLALLAHOU ALAYHE WASALLAM on Windows

Tags: support

I tend to use ﷺ in my answers next to the mention of Prophet Muhammad. The ligature is a condensed form of

> صلى الله عليه وسلم

Which roughly means "may Allah send his peace and blessings upon him".

The [Unicode page](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=FDFA) for this ligature says that U+FDFA, which I should be able to print using

[<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>65018</kbd>](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EF%B7%BA)

When I do this, however, it results in this:

> ·

How can I print this Unicode character without resorting to the stone-age clipboard copy-pasting?

Comment: Is it necessary to include this?  For the purpose of this site, it seems not too different from [greetings](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and it [might not display correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Kge.png) on people's devices.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones there are good [reasons](https://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/176) to include it. I like the conciseness of the symbol - it doesn't detract too much from the main body of text

Comment: Oh wow I can actually do emojis with Alt + a number lol. Never knew that ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Alt codes are truncated and interpreted as ASCII, 65018 mod 256 = 250, which is the ascii code for ·

To enter unicode you need to [change the registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_Microsoft_Windows) to allow for hex alt-codes and then use:

> Alt (hold) + (press + on numpad) FDFA

The above will not work for alphabet hex codes in some programs, including most browsers, instead you will need to use something else.

The following works on chrome:

> Alt (hold) Shift (hold) + (on numpad) FDFA (keys on keypad)

prints ﷺ

Comment: This works in Chrome, as you said. What a roundabout way to get it to work though...